# Show div between two pixel values when scrolling

Tags: javascript

I am trying to show 3 divs (sequentially and when scrolling), and **only between two pixel values ​​for each div**, but there is something about my script that I don't understand:

What I want to show is:

- div-1 only visible between 200 and 500 px
- div-2 only visible between 900 and 1200 px
- div-3 only visible between 1600 and 1900 px

What am I doing wrong here?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p6o7amdh/)** (JSFiddle)

And on the other hand, is there any simpler and more elegant way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

**SCRIP:**

```
$(window).scroll(function() {

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
  //if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 500) {
    $('#div-1').fadeIn();   
  }
  else {
  $('#div-1').fadeOut();
  };

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900) {
  //if (document.body.scrollTop > 900 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 1200) {
    $('#div-2').fadeIn();   
  }
  else {
  $('#div-2').fadeOut();
  };

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1600) {
  //if (document.body.scrollTop > 1600 || document.documentElement.scrollTop < 1900) {
    $('#div-3').fadeIn();   
  }
  else {
  $('#div-3').fadeOut();
  };

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div-1">Radio</div>
<div id="div-2">Blog</div>
<div id="div-3">Store</div>

<div id="content"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div-1,#div-2,#div-3 {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  width:200px;
  height:60px;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
  line-height:60px
}

#div-1{background:#ff0;color:#000}
#div-2{background:#000;color:#fff}
#div-3{background:green;color:#fff}

#content{text-align:center;height:2500px}
```

Comment: You aren't explaining the problem. The jsfiddle looks fine to me because I don't know what I'm looking for. Looking at your code though, I'd change all of the ORs `||` to ANDs `&&`.

Comment: @RyanWheale I am looking to hide (example) the div-1 (between 500 and 900 px) and in JSFiddle it is still visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were just missing `&&`.

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200 && $(this).scrollTop() < 500) {
    // ...
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 900 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1200) {
    // ...
}
if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1600 && $(this).scrollTop() < 1900) {
    // ...
}
```

"If scrolling is greater than 200 AND at the same time the scrolling is less than 500, then show div-1"...

Here is a working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j4me0r3t/)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a couple things:

1. All of your logic should use `&&` instead of `||`
2. You should check the visibility of items before showing or hiding them.
3. You should always store references to commonly accessed DOM elements, especially if you are accessing them inside a scroll event handler (which fires A BUNCH).

OK, that last point is just a performance thing... but you should know it!. Here is an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xebgpduv/

Here's what a block of logic looks like:

```
if (scrollTop > 200 && scrollTop < 500) {
    if(!$div1.is(':visible')) {
        $div1.fadeIn(); 
    }
} else if($div1.is(':visible')) {
    $div1.fadeOut();
};
```